# Sudoku: What is the relationship between minimum number of clues and order n?

Tags: geometric-series, sudoku

A Sudoku puzzle with order $n$ has $n^2 \times n^2$ squares and $n^2$ regions.

For example, a Sudoku puzzle of order $n = 3$ has $9 \times 9$ squares and $9$ regions.

A minimal Sudoku is one with the fewest number of starting clues.

For **1x1** Sudoku of order **n=1**, the minimum number of starting clues is **1**.

For **4x4** Sudoku of order **n=2**, the minimum number of starting clues is **4**.

For **9x9** Sudoku of order **n=3**, the minimum number of starting clues is **17**.

What is the minimum number of starting clues for **16x16** Sudoku of order **n=4**?

Furthermore, if possible,  what is the expression for the relationship between the **minimum number of starting clues** and **order n**?

Answer (score 6):

Given that the solution of the minimal $9 \times 9$ sudoku took the equivalent of [7.1 million core hours on a supercomputer](https://arxiv.org/abs/1201.0749) over 11 calendar months, I suspect that the minimum number for a $16 \times 16$ sudoku will not be solved in the next several decades, even allowing for Moore's Law.  Forget $25 \times 25$.

Comment: That does not mean we can't try to solve it mathematically instead! Humanity shall prevail.

Comment: @CarolineRudolph:  I admire your confidence in "humanity" but as a former professor in both mathematics and computer science (and a former Sudoku addict), I must say that the "rock star" problem of minimal number of constraints just smacks of computation, not math.  Related problems (magic squares) have resisted math attacks for millennia.  Incidentally, I highly recommend the book "Taking Sudoku seriously" by Jason Rosenhouse and Laura Taalman.  Also search YouTube for my TEDx (StanleyPark) talk on sudoku.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't a $1\times 1$ sudoku need $0$ clues to be solved uniquely, so the pattern would actually be, 
$0, 4, 17$?

If the pattern were quadratic (which we have no reason to assume with this few data points), the pattern would be explained with the following:

$$t(n) = 4.5n^2 − 9.5n + 5$$